# Dygraph - is it possible to create an area chart?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Is it possible to create an area chart i.e. shade the area below the line chart with a custom color? I could not see any examples in the gallery and the api reference is pretty huge.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in one of the examples. Basically, use fillGraph option and set it true for a series.

```
 var g3 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("div_g3"),
    function() {
      var ret = "X,Y1,Y2\n";
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ret += i + "," + i + "," + (i * (100-i) * 100/(50*50)) + "\n";
      }
      return ret;
    },
    {
      series: {
        Y1: { fillGraph: true }
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Yep! Or set it for all series at once with `{ fillGraph: true }`.